# ¿Qué función hace "!" delante de una condición?

Tags: java

Mi duda es la siguiente, que función hace el símbolo "!" delante de mi código:

```
 while (!(num >= 1 && num <= 10));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La exclamación delante de una comparación lo que hace es realizar la negación de la misma, por ejemplo:

```
if (1==1) {
   // DO something
}

if (!(1==1)) { 
   // DO something
}
```

En el primer caso entraria en la condición IF en el segundo caso no entraría nunca

**Editado**

El problema lo tienes en la condición esta mal te complicas mucho

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Main{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int num; 

        do{ 
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero comprendido entre 1 y 10"); 
            num = sc.nextInt(); 
        } while (num < 1 && num > 10); 

        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){ 
            System.out.println("La tabla de " + num + " es: " + num * i); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Entonces porqué en mi código: 
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        do{
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero comprendido entre 1 y 10");
            num = sc.nextInt();
        }
        while (!(num >= 1 && num <= 10));
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            System.out.println("La tabla de " + num + " es: " + num * i);
        }
    }
}

su función es proporcionarme la tabla de los números menores de 10?

Comment: ¿Por qué funciona? Le estamos diciendo que lo ejecute siempre y cuando el numero sea menor que uno y mayor que diez. Dos por ejemplo no cumple esas condiciones y aún así ejecuta el código,

Comment: Te equivocas, le estas diciendo que cada vez que un numero cumpla esa condición le pida el numero de nuevo. En el caso del 2 lo pide la primera vez y ya no lo vuelve a pedir ya que no cumple la condición, la primera vez que entra siempre pide el numero

Comment: Es cierto!, ahora todo me cuadra... Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El `while()` se ejecutaría normalmente si `num` es mayor o igual que 1 **y** menor igual que 10.

Al ponerle el simbolo "!" le das la vuelta a la condicion. Es decir: que el `while()` se ejecutaria mientras num **NO** este entre 1 y 10 (ambos incluidos).

Un ejemplo sencillo seria este:

```
bool flag=true;
while(!flag){
  // hago algo
}
```

En este caso el while solo se ejecutara mientras que flag sea distinto de true.

EDIT:

Voy a explicarte tu codigo.

Sin el "!" : Te pido un numero. Si es menor que 10 te vuelvo a pedir un numero porque mi condición es que te siga pidiendo numeros hasta que **NO** sea 1-10.

Con el "!" : Comparas lo contrario a lo que quieres. Es decir que si de normal quieres un 1-10 para continuar con el bucle. Al pedir lo contrario con un 1-10 sales del bucle

Comment: Pero en mi código si no inserto "!", al ejecutar el código y proporcionar al Scanner un número menor que 10 no me ejecuta el For.

Comment: Claro. si quitas el "!" y pones un numero menor que 10  entras otra vez en el while() porque has cumplido la condicion para que se repita

Comment: @AlexCraviotto creo que no tienes muy claro cuando quieres printar los resultados te aconsejo hacer el ejemplo en un papel primero

Comment: Vale, voy a hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

La exclamación '!' niega una sentencia booleana.
Por ejemplo, si tengo una variable

```
boolean cierto = True
```

Si se le pone una exclamación, se convertirá en falso